# Unexpected result with max and min functions in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some troubles with `numpy arrays` and I don't know if it is my computer(I'm having some problems with it) or something else.
At the moment when I introduce the following I these get unexpected results:

```
import numpy as np
names=np.array(['jungle', 'mountain', 'sea', 'lake', 'forest', 'desert', 'house',
 'city', 'mountain'], dtype='<U20')
max(names)
'sea'
min(names)
'city'
```

It should be "mountain" the maximum and "sea" the minimum 
Can anyone reproduce this? Or it is my computer :(

Comment: Note that it's sorting it alphabetically now (with lowercase letters getting sorted before uppercase).  You probably knew that, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: @CodyPiersall, I didn't know it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are compared by the code point of each letter (starting with the first letter, until there is a difference):

```
>>> "AAAAA" < "B"
True
>>> "a" > "A"
True
```

If you want to compare by length instead of case-sensitive "lexicographical" order, use `key=len` as a second argument:

```
max(names, key=len)
```

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't detect automatic that is a string a change to measure the length. There is any documentation about that? in http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max I found the key argument but I didn't know how it works. (I can't mark now the question I will do it later)

Comment: @Llopis: All iterators (and strings are iterators) are compared element by element (unless you override this by providing a `key` argument). Since each element of a string is a character, a string is compared character by character, and they are compared by their code point value.